# Remove the Document default content type from a new document library using Rest API will raise this error "Cannot find resource for the request"

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, power-automate

I have a workflow which creates a new document library, then add a custom content type and remove the document content type. but it is failing when trying to remove the Document content type:-

```
Cannot find resource for the request SP.RequestContext.current/web/lists/getbytitle('2024')/ContentTypes('0x0101')/
```

Here is the flow:-

1. I am getting the ID of the Document content type + I am getting the Id of the custom content type and parse the results:-

[image: johnjohn123_2-1695854536031.png]

2. then i am creating the a new document library:

[image: johnjohn123_3-1695854591607.png]

3. then i am adding the new custom content type:-

[image: johnjohn123_4-1695854622457.png]

4. then finally when i try to remove the Document content type-

[image: johnjohn123_5-1695854652140.png]

I got this error:-

```
Cannot find resource for the request SP.RequestContext.current/web/lists/getbytitle('2024')/ContentTypes('0x0101')/
```

here is the request on runtime:-

[image: johnjohn123_6-1695854861588.png]

so what could be the issue?

Thanks